# CSS div margin auto, cant position element in created margin

Tags: css

I'm creating a small view on my page where I have a centered 500x650 div with some text in it.

I have a bootstrap div as a container, `<div class="container">`. Inside that I have my centered 500x650 div, with a CSS like this:

```
.desc {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 245px 0px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 650px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px dashed #cbd0d8;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

This looks good. Now, I'm trying to add a small image which is supposed to be right by the left bottom corner of the dashed border. Problem is, I centered it with `margin: auto`, creating a huge horizontal margin on the sides of the .desc-div, so I can't position my img, which is in a div with `position: relative`, as the margin pushes it down under the corner.

I could use `position: absolute` on my image but I'm trying to avoid that as I understand it looks different on different sized monitors, and I want this image to sit pretty exactly in one spot.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To place your image exactly into the lower left corner of your `.desc` DIV, put your image tag *inside*  the `.desc` DIV and give it the following settings:

```
img.yourclass {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
 }
```

Since your DIV already has `position: relative`, it will act as the position anchor for the absolutely positioned image, and the bottom and left settings place it in the lower left corner.

The width and height of course depend on the image itself . adjust that as needed.

Comment: I explained myself poorly... I have a scissor-img that I'm trying to position just to the left of the corner, to make it look like it's cutting the dashed border. For that I need it to be the left of the border bottom left corner. So a position: absolute inside the .desc-div doesn't work out :(

Comment: Just adjust the bottom and left settings as needed, or to place it in the upper left corner, use `top` instead of `bottom`